# Abandoned notions in mathematics?

Tags: ho.history-overview, gm.general-mathematics

I'm looking for examples of abandoned or demised notions/concepts in mathematics, preferably (but not necessarily) after the age of foundations. To be clear: I'm not looking for abandoned *ideas* or *theories* (as opposed to notions or concepts); neither am I looking for *revised* (as opposed to abandoned) notions -- I'm aware that there is plenty of both kinds. To illustrate what I'm looking for, consider the notion of phlogiston in natural sciences. Do we have anything like that in math?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Authentic collegial geniality (if there ever was such in mathematics).

Comment: Very similar: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226736/do-mathematical-objects-disappear/226897

Comment: @TomCopeland could you cite some references for this? I'm not familiar with that notion, and Google doesn't seem to be very helpful here.

Comment: @auniket, and benjamin that's a very helpful discussion as well and seems to partly answer the question, (although I'm not necessarily concerned with mathematical *objects* but rather notions).

Comment: @qk11, sorry I just achieved pundit status. You'll have go through the obligatory climb up to my summit before I can answer you.

Comment: A good example is Eliakim Hastings Moore's program in "General Analysis" --- see Reinhard Siegmund-Schultze's 1998 historical survey paper [*Eliakim Hastings Moore's “General Analysis”*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004070050010) and Moore's memoir [*Introduction to a Form of General Analysis*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924051165938/page/n11), pp. vii-viii + 11-50 in **American Mathematical Society Colloquium Publications** #2, Yale University Press, 1910.

Answer (score 5):

How about consulting Euclid's *Elements*?

> The three main classes of irrational magnitudes are the medial, binomial, and apotome. ... It was Euclid who generalized the idea of commensurable and incommensurable to squares, and also ordered the binomial and apotome irrational lines into six distinct classes each (Knorr, 1983).